# Very simple JCombobox cell editor issue

Tags: java, jtable, jcombobox

I'm stumped with something which i'm sure is very simple.

I have a Jcombobox cell editor with an object, lets say 'Customer'.
Customer has a 'code' and a 'description'.
Customer's toString has been overridden to return 'code'.

I have two cells in a table and would like one to list codes, one to list descriptions. Both combobox lists are populated with the Customer object, both return the CODE. How can I make the second combobox show DESCRIPTION?

I tried to create a new sub-class which override the toString method and populating the second combobox with that but in order to load the values into the new sub-type i'd have to regrab the data and create new sub-classes or implement a clone method on the 'customer' object which i'd have to update every time i added a new variable.

Is there a simple way of overriding the jcombobox renderer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple way of overriding the jcombobox renderer?

You need to create your own custom renderer to render a specific property of your Customer object.

The general form of the renderer would be:

```
class FooRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
{
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (value instanceof Foo)
        {
            Foo foo = (Foo)value;
            setText( foo.getDescription() );
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and a more complete implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Detailed and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work to have a conditional statement in the toString method? That seems like it would be easier than overriding JComboBox, if it's possible.

Comment: This is the definitely the easiest solution. A little messy having to set it for each element in the array but unbelievably straight forward!